# Solution verification to a linear algebra 1 exam task

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification, determinant

Given is

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -2\\
 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\in M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$$

and let $f:=L(A):\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear map

$1.$ Which geometric interpretation has $f$

$2.$ Find the matrix $M_B, _B(f)$ of $f$ in relation to the basis $B:=(e_2,e_1+e_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$3.$ Is there a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\det(A^n)=2017$? Explain your choice.

---

**My attempt:**

$1.$ $Ae_1=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\
 2 
\end{pmatrix}$,$\,\, Ae_2=\begin{pmatrix}
 -2 \\
 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

So the map $f$ rotates the input by $90°$ and scales by the factor $2$

$2.$ Im not sure with the notations, but I think what they wanted is:

$_Eid_B=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\Longrightarrow   _Bid_E=\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 1\\
 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$_B(f)=_Bid_E {_EA_E}_Eid_B=\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 1\\
 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -2\\
 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 2\\
 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 4\\
 -2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$

$3.$ No there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\det(A^n)=2017$

Since $\det(A^n)=\det(A)^n=4^n$ which is diviseable by $4$, $\,\,\,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$
And $2017$ is not even.

---

This task was in a older linear algebra 1 exam of a (for me) unknown college. I just wanted to solve it as far as I could, so it would be great if someone could look over it. Actually the notations of the second task are really unknown to me aswell, so I tried making sense of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to parts 1 and 3 look good. In part 2, you've misunderstood what you are asked to find. You should find
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1}^{-1}A\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1}.
$$

Comment: Ahh okey I learned the notation $_Bf_B$ for that :D but no problem at all ;) thank you

Comment: I worked over it, shouldnt it be the correct answer now?

Comment: @CoffeeArabica Yes.